# send a desktop notification to user, when any new data save or update: php, Drupal7

Tags: php, mysql, drupal-7

I have a requirement to send a real-time desktop notification if a database table gets update without any event like page reload or button click.  I am looking some helps in php,Drupal 7,

I have written a script that dows this but it need some event to trigger the Desktop notification.  while i need something that doesn't need event.

Any input would be helpful

Comment: @BilalAhmed I am not asking about any tool here. I have implemented this but it needs some event so looking for some help so we can do it without any event. Hope it make sense to you .

Comment: @BilalAhmed thanks for the link you shared to me but it seems that you gave me the hints of Drupal 8 while I am looking something for Drupal 7. Hope it makes sense to you.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no such functionallity implemented. Try do this with AJAX call

- create `myModuleAjax.js` file with AJAX in loop somewhere in your module eg.

  ```
  (function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.myModuleAjax = {      

      interval: null,

      attach: function (context, settings) {
        interval = setInterval(function() {
          //Place where your php script will be.
          $.getJSON(Drupal.settings.basePath + "ajax/ajaxEventCheck.php", {
              //Any data you need to pass to php script. For example table name.
              tableToCheck: "my_table"
            })
            .done(function(json) {
              //Success, got some data, notification logic here.
              alert("changes");
            })
            .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
              //Handle communication failing.
            });
        //Check each 5 seconds.
        }, 5000);
      },

    }

  } (jQuery));
  ```
- add this script to page

  `drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'myModule') . '/js/myModuleAjax.js');`
- create `ajaxEventCheck.php` script which will check if your event (table update) and return information in JSON, it should be ending with

  ```
  //Your output data is in $data

  //End of function - send JSON data and exit.
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  print json_encode($data);
  die();
  ```

**edit:** assumig this script is outside of drupal dont use `drupal_exit()`, just end script with printed JSON, if you need drupal functionallity inside script this is more tricky, see [this for started](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_bootstrap/7.x)

Those steps should allow you to simulate constant communication between loaded page and backend.

Comment: Exactly. MySQL has no way to push data to an application when something changes. And, drupal has no way to push data to a web browser either. You have to fake "Realtime desktop notification" somehow.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Jacek, but it will continuously hit the server, Do you think it is a good approach.

Comment: It depends. If your script will be simple and optimised, and you will not calling it too often it shouldnt throttle server work (4-5 sec intervals is not "rea-time" but should be easily handled by server, even with other parallel tasks). Eg. If its simple SQL query that should be absolutely fine. Any other approach i can think of are websockets but only thing I found is [this drupal 8 beta module](https://www.drupal.org/project/websocket) which looks abandoned

Comment: @JacekRosłan    yes, i am planning to implement it through nodejs event and socket io.  Thanks for your input here appreciate.